# Trigger a Jenkins job multiple times with different parameter values

Tags: jenkins

I have a job1 that have one choice parameter with many choices.

I'd like to set up a job2 that triggers job1 that many times as there are choices in job1.

I'm trying to use Parametrized Trigger plugin but don't know how to use it to trigger job1 in the way described above.
Any tip is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Declarative Pipelines?

Comment: No, but I think I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a pipeline that triggers the others job with all the jobs names and parameters stored in a map:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def jobParams = [
                        'job1': [
                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'job1-first-parameter-name', value: 'job1-first-parameter-value'],
                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'job1-second-parameter-name', value: 'job1-second-parameter-value']
                        ],
                        'job2': [
                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'job2-first-parameter-name', value: 'job2-first-parameter-value'],
                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'job2-second-parameter-name', value: 'job2-second-parameter-value']
                        ]
                    ]
                    for (def jobName : jobParams.keySet()) {
                        build job: jobName, parameters: jobParams[jobName]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

stages can be ran in [parallel](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#jobs-in-parallel) or one after another :

```
 stage ('Trigger Builds In Parallel') {
        steps {
            parallel (
                param1: {
                    build job: 'job1', parameters: [string(name: 'paramenter-name, value: "parameter-value1")]
                },
                param2: {
                    build job: 'job1', parameters: [string(name: 'paramenter-name, value: "parameter-value2")]
                },
                param3: {
                    build job: 'job1', parameters: [string(name: 'paramenter-name, value: "parameter-value3")]
                },
                failFast: false)
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm experimenting with it now. However, there will be ~100 of jobs, each one with different parameter value. I think I need some loop, so that I don't have to copypaste each paramx: with different parameter.

Comment: I edited to add a loop through a map with job names and parameters for each job.